# Content of some windows degrade over time

Tags: display, windows-11, nvidia

I have the following setup:

- Motherboard: AS Rock
- CPU: Ryzen 9 3900X
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
- Memory: 32Gb
- SSD 1Tb Samsung 970 EVO Plus
- OS: Windows 11 Pro
- Display: Samsung C49RG9xSS
- Resolution: 5120 x 1440

I have a problem with some of the windows degrading over time (blurring). Below is an example:

[image]

[image]

I've tried resetting all NVIDIA settings to the default.
Switch on/off:

- Scaling
- HDR
- G-Sync
- Hardware Accelerated GPU Scheduling

Nothing seems to change anything. Help appreciated.

Apps in which this is happening are:

- WhatApp
- Loxone (example images)

Comment: If you minimise and then restore a problematic window, does it restore the clarity? Or if you can scroll in a window, does that improve it?

Comment: Yes, activating the window does clarify the content again.

Comment: I have a suspicion that it has something to do with WPF and the settings of that which some apps use. For example, the "Your Phone" app on my Windows 10 PC would sometimes show (slightly) blurry text, but I haven't noticed that problem for a while, so, at a guess, they changed some setting (it's called "Phone Link" now).

Comment: I've had the Phone Link open all night but no degradation in that window. I don't think WPF has got to do with this problem. B.t.w. Visual Studio 2022 also is a WPF application, no degradation in that one either. I think it's more HTML related. Both the WhatsApp and Loxone app, I believe, are shells showing a HTML application.